# MySQL cursor multiple values in a variable?

Tags: mysql

I have something like this in a trigger:

```
OPEN cursor_things;
        loop_through_rows : LOOP
            FETCH cursor_things INTO things;

            IF done THEN
                LEAVE loop_through_rows;
            END IF ;
        END LOOP;
 CLOSE cursor_things;
```

Where the SQL is :

```
DECLARE cursor_things CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id
    FROM things
    WHERE thing.id = OLD.id;
```

The problem is that the SQL returns multiple rows and the variable gets overwritten. Is there a way to store multiple values in the variable? Alternatively, is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**
A cursor may not be the best solution. Originally I was just trying a variable:

If we have books and authors tables. Authors have written many books.
I want to get all the ids from the books table

I just want to be able to do this:

```
 INSERT INTO changes (`action`, `data`)
    VALUES ('changed',
            JSON_OBJECT(
                    'author', NEW.author,
                    'book_ids', #how do I get these ids
            )
  );
```

So maybe with something like this:

```
SET bookIds = (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( book_id) from books WHERE author_id = 13);
```

and with a bit more detail, what I actually need is:

```
JSON_OBJECT(
                    'author', NEW.author,
                    'books', [
                    [related book1 id, related book1 type],
                    [related book2 id, related book2 type]
            )
```

Comment: What is the reason to process the rows one-by-one when you need in all values to be retrieved in single variable? Use single aggregate query instead of cursor and aggregate all values into single CSV string or JSON array.

Comment: *the SQL returns multiple rows* Does `thing.id` is not PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: So how can I aggregate them into a JSON array (I want to INSERT it later in the trigger) (it's a pivot table, I'm actually trying to get all the related records)?

Comment: [JSON_ARRAYAGG function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

Comment: Your question looks like [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info). Maybe it's more useful to post the task itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, no, it is not possible to store multiple values in a scalar variable.

I do think there is a better way to accomplish what you describe. Most cases of using a CURSOR in a MySQL procedure can be done in a single query and no loop. For example:

```
INSERT INTO changes (`action`, `data`)
SELECT 'changed', JSON_OBJECT()
  'author', NEW.author,
  'books', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
             JSON_OBJECT(
               'book_id', id,
               'book_type', book_type
             )
           )
FROM books
WHERE author_id = NEW.author;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's pretty much where I have ended up.